# Xamarin NFC view refreshes when trying to write a tag

Tags: xamarin, nfc

I hope I can explain this properly.   Forgive me if I fall short.

I have an Xamarin NFC app for Android that works.  You log into the app, touch the NFC card, it reads the information on the card, you then touch a button to move to a new Intent and then on that View you can type something in, tap the card, and it should write to the card.

What's actually happening in the last view is when you tap the card it refreshes the exact same view, and then you tap again and only then does it write to the NFC card.

So what I think I need to do is to stop NFC sensing on the view that must write to the NFC card - it should only be in write mode, not also in read mode.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

OnNewIntent is not being called the first time the card is tapped.

EDIT - adding in the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Nfc;
using Android.Nfc.Tech;
using Android.Preferences;
using Java.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

namespace [removed]
{
[Activity(Label = "Update Card")]
public class NfcWriter : Activity
{
    public static readonly string PREFERENCE_FILENAME = "[removed]";
    public static readonly string CLIENTID = "CLIENTID";
    public static readonly string CLIENTUSERID = "CLIENTUSERID";

    public static readonly string EMAILADDRESS = "EMAILADDRESS";
    public static readonly string CARDID = "CARDID";
    public static readonly string USERID = "USERID";
    public static readonly string BALANCE = "BALANCE";

    public const string ViewApeMimeType     = "application/[removed]";//"application/[removed]";
    private bool _inWriteMode;
    private NfcAdapter _nfcAdapter;
    private TextView _textView;
    private Button _writeTagButton;
    private AutoCompleteTextView _textEmail;
    public static readonly string Tag = "NFC Writer";
    public static string uuid = "";

    private TextView _textCard;
    private EditText _textAmount;
    private static string cardID;
    private static double balance;
    private static double newBalance;

    private TextView _txtCard;
    private TextView _txtBalance;
    private TextView _txtProduct;
    private TextView _txtTotalPrice;

    private static string layout;

    private double amount = 0.0f;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var c = (Context)this;

        // get the nfc device adapter
        _nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.GetDefaultAdapter(this);

        var allxsSettings = c.GetSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILENAME, FileCreationMode.Private);
        layout = allxsSettings.GetString("Layout", "Registration");


        if (layout == "Registration")
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.writer);
            if (Intent == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            _writeTagButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.write_tag_button);
            _writeTagButton.Click += WriteTagButtonOnClick;

            _textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text_view);

            _textEmail = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.EmailID);
            _textEmail.Text = "";
        }

        if (layout == "CashLoad")
        {
            //_inWriteMode = true;
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoadCash);
            if (Intent == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            _writeTagButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLoadCash);
            _writeTagButton.Click += WriteTagButtonOnClick;

            _textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text_view);

            _textAmount = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtCash);
            _textCard = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCardId);

            cardID = allxsSettings.GetString (CARDID, "");
            var tempBalance = allxsSettings.GetFloat(BALANCE, 0.0f);
            balance = Convert.ToDouble(tempBalance);

            _textCard.Text = cardID;
            _textAmount.Text = "";
        }

        if (layout == "Sale") {
            //_inWriteMode = true;
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Sale);
            if (Intent == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            _writeTagButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSale);
            _writeTagButton.Click += WriteTagButtonOnClick;

            _textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text_view);

            _txtBalance= FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCash);
            _txtCard = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCardId);
            _txtProduct=FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtProduct);
            _txtTotalPrice=FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtPrice);

            cardID = allxsSettings.GetString (CARDID, "");
            var tempBalance = allxsSettings.GetFloat (BALANCE, 0.0f);
            balance = Convert.ToDouble(tempBalance);

            _txtCard.Text = cardID;
            _txtBalance.Text = balance.ToString("0.00");

            Product productRow = null;

            decimal totalAmount = 0;
            _txtProduct.Text = "";

            foreach (var salesRow in SalesManager.GetSaless()) {
                productRow = ProductManager.GetProduct (salesRow.ProductID);

                totalAmount += Convert.ToDecimal (salesRow.TotalAmount);

                if (_txtProduct.Text.Length != 0)
                    _txtProduct.Text += "\n";

                _txtProduct.Text += salesRow.NoOfUnits + " x " + productRow.ProductName + " @ " + productRow.UnitPrice.ToString ("0.00");
            }

            _txtTotalPrice.Text = totalAmount.ToString("0.00");

            // determine the new card balance
            newBalance = balance - Convert.ToDouble (totalAmount);

            if (newBalance < 0) {
                // we don't have enough money to buy
                _txtTotalPrice.Text += " INSUFFICIENT FUNDS";

                toast ("INSUFFICIENT FUNDS - NO SALE");
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called when an NFC tag is discovered by the application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="intent"></param>
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        _inWriteMode = true;

        if (_inWriteMode)
        {
            //_inWriteMode = false;

            var c = (Context)this;
            var allxsSettings = c.GetSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILENAME, FileCreationMode.Private);

            var tag = intent.GetParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraTag) as Tag;
            if (tag == null)
            {
                return;
            }


            Card card = new Card ();
            if (layout == "Registration") {

                card.CardID = _textEmail.Text;
                card.Amount = 0.0f;
            } 
            if (layout == "CashLoad") {
                card.CardID = _textCard.Text;
                card.Amount = balance;
            }

            if (layout == "Sale") {

                // no write allowed if there is no money
                if (newBalance < 0) {
                    toast ("INSUFFICIENT FUNDS - NO SALE");
                    return;
                }

                var cardID = allxsSettings.GetString (CARDID, "");
                var tempBalance = allxsSettings.GetFloat (BALANCE, 0.0f);
                var balance = Convert.ToDouble(tempBalance);
                var clientUserId = allxsSettings.GetInt (CLIENTUSERID, 0);

                card.CardID = cardID;
                card.Amount = newBalance;
            }


            BinaryFormatter payload = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            payload.Serialize(ms, card);

            var mimeBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ViewApeMimeType);
            var cardRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TnfMimeMedia, mimeBytes, new byte[0], ms.ToArray());
            var ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(new[] { cardRecord });

            bool isWritten = false;

            if (!TryAndWriteToTag(tag, ndefMessage))
            {
                // Maybe the write couldn't happen because the tag wasn't formatted?
                if (TryAndFormatTagWithMessage(tag, ndefMessage))
                    isWritten = true;

            }
            else
            {
                isWritten = true;
            }

            // if we did write to the card then we must update the server api (this is where the transaction should be stored locally and updated later)
            if (isWritten)
            {
                if (layout == "Registration")
                {
                    // this is a new card - we don't know who the user is at this time but send the card registration to the system
                    ApiCardRegistration(card.CardID);
                }

                if (layout == "CashLoad")
                {
                    // tell the api that we have loaded cash
                    ApiCardLoadCash(card.CardID, amount);
                }

                if (layout == "Sale")
                {
                    // we have written the sale amount to the card, now write to the server
                    ApiCardLoadProducts (card.CardID);

                }
            }


            ISharedPreferencesEditor prefEditor = allxsSettings.Edit();
            prefEditor.PutString("Layout", "");     
            prefEditor.Apply();
            prefEditor.Commit();

        }
    }




    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        // App is paused, so no need to keep an eye out for NFC tags.
        if (_nfcAdapter != null)
            _nfcAdapter.DisableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    private void DisplayMessage(string message)
    {
        _textView.Text = message;
        //Log.Info(Tag, message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identify to Android that this activity wants to be notified when 
    /// an NFC tag is discovered. 
    /// </summary>
    private void EnableWriteMode()
    {
        _inWriteMode = true;

        // Create an intent filter for when an NFC tag is discovered.  When
        // the NFC tag is discovered, Android will u
        var tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ActionTagDiscovered);
        var filters = new[] { tagDetected };

        // When an NFC tag is detected, Android will use the PendingIntent to come back to this activity.
        // The OnNewIntent method will invoked by Android.


        var intent = new Intent(this, GetType()).AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        if (_nfcAdapter == null)
        {
            var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create();
            alert.SetMessage("NFC is not supported on this device.");
            alert.SetTitle("NFC Unavailable");
            alert.SetButton("OK", delegate
                {
                    _writeTagButton.Enabled = false;
                    _textView.Text = "NFC is not supported on this device.";
                });
            alert.Show();
        }
        else
            _nfcAdapter.EnableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, filters, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tag"></param>
    /// <param name="ndefMessage"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool TryAndFormatTagWithMessage(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage)
    {
        var format = NdefFormatable.Get(tag);
        if (format == null)
        {
            DisplayMessage("Tag does not appear to support NDEF format.");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                format.Connect();

                format.Format(ndefMessage);
                DisplayMessage("Tag successfully written.");


                return true;
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioex)
            {
                var msg = "There was an error trying to format the tag.";
                DisplayMessage(msg);
                //Log.Error(Tag, ioex, msg);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    private void WriteTagButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var view = (View)sender;
        if (view.Id == Resource.Id.write_tag_button)
        {
            DisplayMessage("Touch and hold the tag against the phone to write.");
            EnableWriteMode();
        }

        if (view.Id == Resource.Id.btnLoadCash)
        {

            if (_textAmount.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
                toast("Please enter Amount.");
            else
            {
                if (_textCard.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    toast("Please enter Card Number");
                    return;
                }

                amount = 0;

                try
                {
                    amount = Convert.ToDouble(_textAmount.Text.Trim());
                }
                catch
                {
                    toast("Invalid Amount");
                    return;
                }

                if (cardID == "")
                    cardID = _textCard.Text;

                balance += amount;
                DisplayMessage("Touch and hold the tag against the phone to write.");
                EnableWriteMode();
            }




        }
        if (view.Id == Resource.Id.btnSale) {
            DisplayMessage("Touch and hold the tag against the phone to write.");
            EnableWriteMode();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This method will try and write the specified message to the provided tag. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tag">The NFC tag that was detected.</param>
    /// <param name="ndefMessage">An NDEF message to write.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the tag was written to.</returns>
    private bool TryAndWriteToTag(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage)
    {

        // This object is used to get information about the NFC tag as 
        // well as perform operations on it.
        var ndef = Ndef.Get(tag);
        if (ndef != null)
        {
            ndef.Connect();

            // Once written to, a tag can be marked as read-only - check for this.
            if (!ndef.IsWritable)
            {
                DisplayMessage("Tag is read-only.");
            }

            // NFC tags can only store a small amount of data, this depends on the type of tag its.
            var size = ndefMessage.ToByteArray().Length;
            if (ndef.MaxSize < size)
            {
                DisplayMessage("Tag doesn't have enough space.");
            }

            ndef.WriteNdefMessage(ndefMessage);
            DisplayMessage("Succesfully wrote tag.");
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What mechanism are you using to catch the NFC intent? If you don't use the foreground dispatch, than you might want to look into that.

Comment: @corvairjo I am using foreground despatch - same as the standard examples.

Comment: @Wonderboy Would you mind showing us some of the code that results in that behavior?

Comment: You have no onResume() method. I usually store the state whether EnableForegroundDispatch should be active, and set it again in onResume().

Comment: One more hint: I use not only ACTION_TagDiscovered as IntentFilter, but also ACTION_NDEF_Discovered. See:         IntentFilter ndefDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);  ndefDetected.addDataScheme(context.getResources().getString(R.string.MAGIC_SCHEME));   ndefDetected.addDataAuthority(context.getResources().getString(R.string.MAGIC_HOST), null); ndefDetected.addDataPath(context.getResources().getString(R.string.MAGIC_PATH), 0);
mReadTagFiltersNdef = new IntentFilter[] {ndefDetected};
IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);

Comment: @corvairjo the TAG_DISCOVERED intent filter is a catch-all (actually it would be better to pass null to the enableForegroundDIspatch method instead of any intent filter) so using NDEF DISCOVERED in addition is redundant.

Comment: The NFC card is being detected, however the action/page that appears is exactly the same one that was supposed to write to the card.  It is the write page, and I capture some text, start the write process - tap the card, and instead of writing to the card the page refreshes.   Then I have to type in some text again, start the write process - and tap the card, and this time it writes to the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the way the NfcWriter class intent was being started.   The code above wasn't the problem, as I never had to make any changes except to the way the intent was created.

I replaced "this" with "Application.ApplicationContext" and set the flag to "NewTask" in the calling code, which became this ...

```
Android.Content.Intent intent = new Intent(Application.ApplicationContext, typeof(NfcWriter));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

StartActivity(intent);
```

I hope this can help someone else.

I derived this with some clever help from a Xamarin support person, Brendan - who guided me to create NFC logs from the interactions and then study the logs to work out where the problem was.

The thing that helped me most was in the NFC log, finding this error - "startActivity called from non-Activity context", and a lot of trial and error.

To get to the NFC logs you can follow these steps:

1. Connect the Android device to your computer so that you can send it 'adb' commands
2. Clear the logs with 'adb logcat -c', optional to make the logs easier to read
3. Perform the steps on the device to reproduce the problem
4. Collect all of the 'adb logcat' logs

   - adb logcat -d -vtime > C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\nfc_logcat.txt
   - adb logcat -d -vtime -bradio > C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\nfc_radio.txt
   - adb logcat -d -vtime -bevents > C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\nfc_events.txt

On Windows, the default install location for `adb` when using the Xamarin installer is:
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe